# Error accessing nested array of objects in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to consume json coming from a webapi. When debugging, the data is coming through correctly as per picture below:

[image]

Surprisingly when I try to loop through the objects in the report.subreport array, I get told it's undefined:

```
getReports() {
    console.log('Get Reports');
    this.staticEventsService.getReports().subscribe((rep) => {
      this.reports = rep as Report[];
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
      debugger;
      this.reports.forEach(r => {
        r.subreport.forEach(s => { console.log('subreport = ' + s.categoryId);});});
      console.log('show me the god damn reports = ' + this.reports);
    });
```

[image]

I've declared these classes to deal with the incoming data:

```
export class Report {
  month: number;
  subreport: SubReport[];
  };

export class SubReport {
  categoryId: number;
  occurrences: number;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. I see that you used `subreport` and it should be `subReport` with a capital `R`.

Comment: What a waste of 5 hours of my life.

Answer (score 1):

Error came from ‘r.subreport.forEach’.Following your debug image, It should be ‘r.subReport.forEach’ (R instead of r).

I guess you have to update your Report type, or update the service response to match with your Report type.